# How could I use peak_detection function - Android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use [this](https://gist.github.com/tiraeth/1306602) function but I'm running into some errors. I would to use this function tu detect a peak in real-time from FastICA implementation about RGB image from android camera. I'm using into first parameter `Double[] Green = ArrayUtils.toObject(arrayGreen);` output of FastICA is working fine. I'm using `double delta=10;` into second parameter and is fine. I have a problem using the third parameter because I'm not understanding which is the third parameter I need.
I've tried to create an `List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();` but not working. Could anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance

code I'm trying:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class CustomUtils {


    /**
     * Detects peaks (calculates local minima and maxima) in the 
     * vector <code>values</code>. The resulting list contains
     * maxima at the first position and minima at the last one.
     * 
     * Maxima and minima maps contain the indice value for a
     * given position and the value from a corresponding vector.
     * 
     * A point is considered a maximum peak if it has the maximal
     * value, and was preceded (to the left) by a value lower by
     * <code>delta</code>.
     * 
     * @param values Vector of values for whom the peaks should be detected
     * @param delta The precedor of a maximum peak
     * @param indices Vector of indices that replace positions in resulting maps
     * @return List of maps (maxima and minima pairs) of detected peaks
     */
    public static <U> List<Map<U, Double>> peak_detection(List<Double> values, Double delta, List<U> indices)
    {
        assert(indices != null);
        assert(values.size() != indices.size());

        Map<U, Double> maxima = new HashMap<U, Double>();
        Map<U, Double> minima = new HashMap<U, Double>();
        List<Map<U, Double>> peaks = new ArrayList<Map<U, Double>>();
        peaks.add(maxima);
        peaks.add(minima);

        Double maximum = null;
        Double minimum = null;
        U maximumPos = null;
        U minimumPos = null;

        boolean lookForMax = true;

        Integer pos = 0;
        for (Double value : values) {
            if (value > maximum || maximum == null) {
                maximum = value;
                maximumPos = indices.get(pos);
            }

            if (value < minimum || minimum == null) {
                minimum = value;
                minimumPos = indices.get(pos);
            }

            if (lookForMax) {
                if (value < maximum - delta) {
                    maxima.put(maximumPos, value);
                    minimum = value;
                    minimumPos = indices.get(pos);
                    lookForMax = false;
                }
            } else {
                if (value > minimum + delta) {
                    minima.put(minimumPos, value);
                    maximum = value;
                    maximumPos = indices.get(pos);
                    lookForMax = true;
                }
            }

            pos++;
        }

        return peaks;
    }

    /**
     * Detects peaks (calculates local minima and maxima) in the 
     * vector <code>values</code>. The resulting list contains
     * maxima at the first position and minima at the last one.
     * 
     * Maxima and minima maps contain the position for a
     * given value and the value itself from a corresponding vector.
     * 
     * A point is considered a maximum peak if it has the maximal
     * value, and was preceded (to the left) by a value lower by
     * <code>delta</code>.
     * 
     * @param values Vector of values for whom the peaks should be detected
     * @param delta The precedor of a maximum peak
     * @return List of maps (maxima and minima pairs) of detected peaks
     */
    public static List<Map<Integer, Double>> peak_detection(List<Double> values, Double delta)
    {
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<values.size(); i++) {
            indices.add(i);
        }

        return ANPRUtils.peak_detection(values, delta, indices);
    }

}
```

**Edit**
Using the second function into the first I'm running into this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter is a little weird-  its a list of names for the corresponding minima and maxima.  So lets say there's 1 at position 1 in the data, and you pass it a 3rd parameter with the list ("A", "B", "C").  The return value will be a map ("B"-> maxima value).

Its weird code and I'm not sure why they did it that way.  It seems a very inconvenient way to do things.  Also, I think their code will crash if indices.size() < values.size()

Notice their 2 value version of the function is passing in an array of (1,2,3,4,...n) where n is the number of values in the data.  In that case, the return value will be a map of (position index->maxima/minima value).  Which seems to be the only way you should use this.

Comment: Thanks Gabe Sechan. If I try to declare _List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();_ and inside my function for facetracking I try to implement for loop like second  version I'm run into error too. I will edit with a screen of error

Comment: It returns a Map<Integer, Double>.  You're trying to store it in a double[].  That won't work, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Yes I know. Using : List<Map<Integer, Double>> peack = PeakDetect.peak_detection(Greenlist,delta, indices); I don't have errors but running the code I have a new problem: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.PeakDetect.peak_detection(PeakDetect.java:29)

Comment: have you got some suggestion about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253413/rgb-face-detection-image-how-to-find-a-peaks-in-double-array-with-neighborhoo) question?